# c# DateTime. Reset time to 0

Tags: c#, datetime

I have dateTime = `3/25/2020 1:25:46 PM`
Can I reset time to zero? `3/25/2020 00:00:00`

Here is a demo. In this case dateTime is `3/25/2020 12:00:00 AM`

```
class Program
{
    static  void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var datetime = DateTime.Now;
        datetime = ResetTimeToStartOfDay(datetime);

        Console.WriteLine(datetime);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static DateTime ResetTimeToStartOfDay(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return new DateTime(
           dateTime.Year,
           dateTime.Month,
           dateTime.Day,
           0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

How to reset the date to the beginning of the day?

Comment: FYI 12 AM is the beginning of the day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

more simply:

```cs
return dateTime.Date;
```

But note that in the specific case of `DateTime.Now` you could just use `DateTime.Today` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> How to reset the date to the beginning of the day?

You already are in your method `ResetTimeToStartOfDay` although there is an easier way to do it with `dateTime.Date` which is functionally equivalent.

So your question now becomes:

> Why do you see `3/25/2020 12:00:00 AM` instead of `3/25/2020 00:00:00` when `Console.WriteLine(datetime);` is called.

When you call `ToString()` on the `DateTime` instance, which happens implicitly in `Console.WriteLine(datetime);`, the displayed format matches the culture of the current thread which then displays the time using `AM/PM`. If you want to display the date as `3/25/2020 00:00:00` then call `ToString()` explicitly and pass a [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) like `M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

`Console.WriteLine(datetime.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));`

See also [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public static DateTime SetTimeToZero(DateTime YourDate)
{
    return new DateTime(YourDate.Year, YourDate.Month, YourDate.Day, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

or you can create an `ExtensionMethod` and use inside your project:

```
public static DateTime SetTimeToZero(this DateTime YourDate)
{
    return new DateTime(YourDate.Year, YourDate.Month, YourDate.Day, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

How to use `ExtensionMethod`:

```
yourDatetime.SetTimeToZero(date);
```